# How to collect time periods, calculate the total, and present in ISO 8601 format?

Tags: datetime

I am trying to get few inputs of time periods from users (it can be by choosing in dropdown).
let's say a user will be able to input in one field: "1 hour and 5 minutes" or 01:05;
In second field the user will be able to input: "2 hours and 25 minutes" or 02:25;

Then, I want to calculate and add up the  two time peirods for: "3 hours and 30 minutes" or 03:30;

It's important that all the date and time fields will be saved in ISO 8601 format, for google.

Someone can help, How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I saw that Here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=en 
"The date that the item was reviewed in ISO date format."
SO, what should I do?

Comment: Thank you for your very kind comment.
I explain that I need to collect time period / time field / I don't know how to else call it / hours and minutes / e.g "1 hour and 5 minutes".
Can someone please explain to me (since I am a newbie) what I need to do, in order for google to be able to read my data ? And how can I define a field that will calculate. e.g.: ("1 hour and 5 minutes" or 01:05) + ("2 hours and 25 minutes" or 02:25) = ("3 hours and 30 minutes" or 03:30)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking two completely unrelated questions here.  To rephrase:

1. How can I provide Google with dates in a format that Google's scraper will recognize, as specified in [Rich snippets - Reviews](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=en)?
2. How can I accumulate time periods and present the result in a format suitable for humans?

Asking two unrelated question in one question is depreciated on SE, and will usually get your question closed, but I am going to answer them anyway.

**First question**: The ISO 8601 format requested by Google is `YYYY-MM-DD` with leading zeros if required, so July the 4th 2013 would be `2013-07-04`.

To format the ISO date you can use the PHP function [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) like this:

```
$isodate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

where `$timestamp` is an integer with the number of seconds that has elapsed since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Further, Google expects the `$isodate` string to be embedded in the page attached to the `dtreviewed` property using the syntax one of three metadata schemes (microdata, microformats, or RFDa).  You do this in Drupal by [overriding the template](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-overrides/) of page, node, etc. you want to embed the `dtreviewed` property in.

**Second question**: To accumulate time periods, you need to convert periods input by users (such as "1 hour and 5 minutes" or "01:05") to an integer format with seconds resolution.  To convert to seconds you multiply the days with 86400, the hours with 3600 and the minutes with 60, so "1 hour and 5 minutes" becomes:

```
1 (hour) * 3600 + 5 (minutes) * 60 + 0 (seconds) = 3900 (seconds)
```

and  "2 hours and 25 minutes" becomes:

```
2 (hour) * 3600 + 25 (minutes) * 60 + 0 (seconds) = 8700 (seconds)
```

To accumulate, you just add the seconds:

```
3900 + 8700 = 12600 (seconds)
```

To display in a suitable format, you can use [`format_interval`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_interval/7).

```
$interval = 3900 + 8700;
$intervalstring = format_interval($interval, 2);
```

and `$intervalstring` will now be:

```
3 hours 30 minutes
```

(You will lose the "and" by using this standard function, if this "and" is important, you'll need to write your own.)

For avoidance of misunderstanding: Goggle is *not* interested in your time period data. A time period is typically an interval made up of **hours** and **minutes**, and not attached to a particular date.  Google wants dates (as in **year**, **month** and **day of month**).  Dates and time periods are different things, and there is no way you can format a *time period* as a *date*, or vice versa.

Comment: first of all, Many thanks for your great explanation!
second, it was unclear for me before I asked. I need two formats: 1.The date that the item was reviewed in ISO date format. link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=en 2.The total time it takes to prepare the cook the dish, in ISO 8601 duration format. Can use min, max as child elements to specify a range of time. link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/173379?hl=en&ref_topic=1088474. So I really needs both.
for this I will need "interval made up of hours and minutes"? Can I get the duration the same way?